# C++ class name as class member

Tags: c++

What's the meaning of the postfix expression `AttrNode().AttrNode` in `main` in the following code? Both gcc and clang can compile the code without any error. Seems it is legal in C++ standards. But what's the meaning of such code? Why does the C++ standards allow such usage?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct AttrNode {
public:
     AttrNode() {}
     static void make() {}
};

int main() {
    AttrNode().AttrNode::make();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What peculiar code! Creating a temporary instance for literally no reason, and qualifying the function name for literally no reason. Only one of those things should be done, and it's certainly not the former!

Answer (score 8):

`AttrNode::` is qualifying the name `make`, to explicitly call `AttrNode::make` and not any other function called `make`.

In this case, that's redundant; `AttrNode().make()` would do exactly the same thing: create a temporary object, call the function, then destroy the object. Since it's a static function, you would usually call it without making an object, `AttrNode::make()`.

It makes a difference if it's a virtual function, causing a non-virtual call to the function in the specified class, rather than a virtual call the final override. The syntax can also be used to access a name in the base class that's been hidden in a derived class.

Comment: One thing that needs to be mentioned is that whether calling the static function with or without making an object differs in the effect of creating the object. Of course, it does not make any difference in this example.

Comment: @writalnaie: OK, I've made it slightly clearer that the posted code creates a (probably unwanted) object while a regular static function call doesn't.